# how to disable combobox auto selected in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I bind the combo-box to a new data-source, it will automatically select the first item. How do I disable that?
this my code :

```
 Private Sub item_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim obj As New config


        con1 = New SqlConnection
        con1 = obj.getcontion()
        con1.Open()



        da = New SqlDataAdapter("select  *  from item", con1)
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "item")
        cmbItem.DataSource = ds
        cmbItem.DisplayMember = "item.itemname"


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent `combobox` from being selected.

```
cmbItem.DataSource = ds
cmbItem.SelectedIndex=-1
```

Note: You've to set`SelectedIndex` property to `-1` **after** binding `combobox` with `datasource`.

---

To show custom text("`Select an item`"),

```
 da = New SqlDataAdapter("select  *  from item", con1)
 ds = New DataSet
 da.Fill(ds, "item")
 Dim firstRow As DataRow = ds.Tables("item").NewRow
 firstRow("itemname") = "Select an item"
 ds.Tables("item").Rows.InsertAt(firstRow, 0)
 cmbItem.DataSource = ds
 cmbItem.DisplayMember = "item.itemname"
 cmbItem.SelectedIndex = 0
```